# Order Mongoose/MongoDB query results by number of values not in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections with the following simplified schemas:

```
// Ingredient 
{
  _id: Number
}

// Recipe
{
  _id: Number,
  ingredients: [{
    type: Number,
    ref: 'Ingredient'
  }]
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a search query for recipes based on what ingredients you have available, sorted by the number of ingredients missing from each recipe.

For example, if I have the following data:

```
// Ingredients
{
  _id: 1
},
{
  _id: 2
},
{
  _id: 3
},
{ 
  _id: 4
},
{
  _id: 5
}

// Recipes
{
  _id: 1,
  ingredients: [1, 2, 5]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  ingredients: [2, 4]
},
{
  _id: 3,
  ingredients: [2, 3]
}
```

and I input ingredients 2 and 3, the expected results would be

```
{
  _id: 3,
  ingredients: [2, 3] // Missing 0 ingredients
},
{
  _id: 2,
  ingredients: [2, 4] // Missing 1 ingredient
},
{
  _id: 1,
  ingredients: [1, 2, 5] // Missing 2 ingredients
}
```

Is it possible to do this with a query alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) to find the missing ingredients, and then [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) to get their count that you can then `$sort` on.

```javascript
var ingredients = [2, 3];
db.recipes.aggregate([
    {$project: {missing: {$setDifference: ['$ingredients', ingredients]}}},
    {$project: {missing: 1, numMissing: {$size: '$missing'}}},
    {$sort: {numMissing: 1}}
])
```

Results:

```javascript
{ "_id" : 3, "missing" : [ ], "numMissing" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 2, "missing" : [ 4 ], "numMissing" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1, "missing" : [ 1, 5 ], "numMissing" : 2 }
```